# node express html sendfile and json data ; angular loads the json data into the htmls

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js

I want node and express to send a file and json data together as the response. The routing is also done on the client side( which uses Angular ui router) --

So here the facebook redirect route after successful validation(using passport) --

```
// =====================================
// FACEBOOK ROUTES =====================
// =====================================
// route for facebook authentication and login
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : 'email' }));

// handle the callback after facebook has authenticated the user
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook'), function(req, res){
        res.send(req.user);
    });
```

But i want the profile html page to be loaded thru angular which would need the json response data from the profile route - how to do that ?

Index file --

```
<a href="/auth/facebook" target="_self" ng-click="vm.loadProfile()" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span> Facebook</a>
```

Controller -

```
vm.loadProfile = function(){
        authFactory.getFBCallbackData().success(function(data){
            vm.loadProfileData(data);
        }).error(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    vm.loadProfileData = function(data){
        console.log(data);
        if(data.status === "success"){
            $state.go('profile');
            vm.profileData = data.userInfo;
        }
    }
```

AuthFactory --

```
getFBCallbackData: function(){return $http.get('/auth/facebook/callback');}
```

How to get the above "data" to load from the route?

Comment: these links might help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData